# Emacs modes to deal with .prima files

Tags: database, emacs, prisma, major-mode

My schema.prisma file (https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema) is on Fundamental mode.

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

I would like to use some programming support in this file also. It's similar to JSON files, but not quite. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you meant by programming support ? What you're trying to achieve maybe ? If its autocompletion, linting, syntax highlighting related to `.prisma` files you can refer [environment & IDE setup doc](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/development-environment/editor-setup)

Comment: That's exactly it. I didn't find any package support in the standard emacs libraries (MELPA etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[emacs-prisma-mode](https://github.com/pimeys/emacs-prisma-mode) provides a emacs mode for Prisma schemas. I found it in the [editor setup page](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/development-environment/editor-setup) in the Prisma docs.

This should be what you're looking for.